# ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, drivers, odbc

Morning,

Some background:

- Recently upgraded database and web servers from Server 2008R2 => 2016 OS
- Recently upgraded database instances from SQL Server 2008R2 => 2016
- Recently upgraded the ODBC driver to ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
- Using DSN's. Unsure about other config's (don't have full access to server settings atm)

The problem:
One example: Vbscript is calling a stored procedure with a simple delete from a Clasp page written in vbscript. The delete happens, but it catches this error:

- Desc: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Executing
  SQL directly; no cursor
- Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers
- SQL State: 01000
- Native Error: 16954

I've been unable to find much information about what this means "Executing SQL directly; no cursor"

Anyone drop me a breadcrumb?

Thanks, D

Comment: Well...I think we're using the wrong driver. I understand that Microsoft has split the driver dll up into two drivers:
ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server and OLE DB Driver 18 for SQL Server. I'll let you know how it works out

Comment: Calling OLE DB driver directly fixed the error. Provider= MSOLEDBSQL